# Nothing is displayed when trying to connect to Sybase SQL Anywhere under CYGWIN

Tags: cygwin, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to work with dbisql (Sybase SqlAnywhere client) under CYGWIN but the database prompt (shell) is not displayed on screen and then the client exists.

This is how I'm trying to connect

```
sqlanywhere@win2012r2:  dbisql -c "UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=demo;host=10.100.49.124" -nogui
```

Does anyone know how to solve this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is to explicitly use 'dbisql.com' rather than 'dbisql', which will invoke 'dbisql.exe' which doesn't work well under Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks! It's working! Can you please elaborate on the difference between the .com and .exe files?

Comment: dbisql.com is a 'console application', while dbisql.exe is a windowed app. Normally in Windows, when no suffix is specified, .com is executed before .exe. So normally, dbisql.com is executed first; when it sees from the options specified that the windowed app is started, it fires dbisql.exe. However, in Cygwin it's the other way round so .exe is started first. With -nogui, things don't work out then.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Adding cmd /c before the dbisql starting the client did the trick

```
sqlanywhere@win2012r2:  dbisql -c "UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=demo;host=10.100.49.124" -nogui select from temptbl

sqlanywhere@win2012r2: cmd /c dbisql -c "UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=demo;host=10.100.49.124" -nogui

(DBA)> quit
sqlanywhere@win2012r2:
```